# What should I do if I have another question about an asked question

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I had a question about the phrase "tend to" and I found this question which asks about this phrase:
[meaning of "tend to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166666/meaning-of-tend-to)
But now I have a question about the text example in this question.
Should I ask it in comment ? or post another question?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

If you are asking the person that wrote the text for clarification about what they said, it probably should be a comment.

If you are asking about the English of the text, or about a “rule” that someone put forth, you should post another question, include a link to the question that had the text you'd like to ask about, and explain what you found when you looked for an answer before you posted.

Comments aren’t searchable, so if someone else has the same question that you had, they won’t be able to find any answer you might get if you ask in a comment. If you post a question you might help other learners.